# select all products from child categories in parent category

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following 'categories' table:

```
+--------+---------------+----------------------------------------+
| ID     | Parent ID     | Name                                   |
+--------+---------------+----------------------------------------+
| 1      | 0             | Computers                              |
| 2      | 1             | Apple                                  |
| 3      | 1             | HP                                     |
| 4      | 2             | Macbook Air                            |
| 5      | 2             | Macbook Pro                            |
| 6      | 1             | Dell                                   |
| 7      | 6             | Inspiron                               |
| 8      | 6             | Alienware                              |
| 9      | 8             | Alienware 13                           |
| 10     | 8             | Alienware 15                           |
| 11     | 8             | Alienware 17                           |
| 12     | 0             | Smartphones                            |
| 13     | 12            | Apple                                  |
| 14     | 12            | Samsung                                |
| 15     | 12            | LG                                     |
+--------+---------------+----------------------------------------+
```

Let's say I have the following 'products' table:

```
+--------+---------------+----------------------------------------+
| ID     | Category ID   | Name                                   |
+--------+---------------+----------------------------------------+
| 1      | 13            | Apple iPhone 8                         |
| 2      | 13            | Apple iPhone 8 Plus                    |
| 3      | 14            | Samsung Galaxy S8                      |
+--------+---------------+----------------------------------------+
```

With the following query, I select all the products in a category:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name
FROM
    products
WHERE
    category_id = ?
```

**Ok, my question:**

The product 'Apple iPhone 8' is in the category *Apple*, this is a subcategory of the category *Smartphones*. If I replace the '?' in my query with 13 (the category ID of *Apple*), I get the product. When I replace the '?' in my query with 12 (the category ID of *Smartphones*), I don't get the product. I want to select all products that are **in the category or in one of the child/grandchild/... categories**. How can I do this with a single query (if possible)?

Comment: Could you post expected output for `category_id=13` ?

Comment: I’d do this with PHP in addition to MySQL. One query to get all children/grandchildren categories. Process results in PHP to build a second query to get all products in those categories.

Comment: Also: this question/answer looks relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20215744/1967095

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `join` .
your `query` should be like this

```
SELECT
    id,
    name
FROM
    products
JOIN 
    categories
ON 
    products.category_id = categories.id;
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using join

SELECT
    id,
    name
FROM
    products
JOIN 
    categories
ON 
    products.category_id = categories.id
WHERE products.category_id = 13 OR categories.parent_id = 12

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id, name FROM products LEFT JOIN categories ON products.category_id = categories.id

Answer (score 0):

1) A QUERY. I'm taking a query from this answer. 
[How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query) Please read it for a full explanation of the query. The query assumes that the parent ID will be less than the child IDs (like 19 is less than 20,21,22).

```
select * from products where `Category ID` in 
    (select ID from 
    (select * from categories order by `Parent ID`, ID) categories_sorted, 
    (select @pv := '12') initialisation 
    where (find_in_set(`Parent ID`, @pv) > 0 
    and @pv := concat(@pv, ',', ID)) or ID = @pv)
```

You have to set the "12" to be whatever the parent category is.

2) Via two sections in PHP, one that loops until you have all category IDs. Then a second section that gets all products in those categories. This is far more verbose but I like how clear you can see what is happening.

```
$db = new mysqli(host, user, password, database);

$all_ids = []; // total ids found, starts empty
$new_ids = [12]; // put parent ID here

do {

    // master list of IDs
    $all_ids = array_merge($new_ids, $all_ids);

    // set up query
    $set = "(".implode($new_ids, ',').")";
    $sql = "select ID from categories where `Parent ID` in $set";

    // find any more parent IDs?
   $new_ids = []; // reset to nothing
   $rows = $db->query($sql) or die("DB error: (" . $db->errno . ") " . $db->error);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) {
        $new_ids[] = $row['ID'];
    }

} while (count($new_ids) > 0);    


// get products
$set = "(".implode($all_ids, ',').")";
$sql = "select * from products where `Category ID` in $set";
$rows = $db->query($sql) or die("DB error: (" . $db->errno . ") " . $db->error);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) {
    echo "{$row['Name']}<br>\n";
}
```